# text editing using tr command

Tags: command-line, execute-command, convert-command

On using the command:

```
tr -s '\n' ' '< test1
```

where test1 is a text file.

If test1 is written in a manner such that it contains newlines (linefeed characters) and not \n (backslash-n) then the answer comes as expected that is all the newlines get replaced by a single space.

But if say the test1 is formatted such that it contains \n (backslash-n) and not a newline then running the command the \n does not get replaced by a single space, E.g. if test1 contains

```
hello \n\n\n how are \n\n you
```

then the output is

```
hello \n\n\n how are \n\n you
```

and not

```
hello   how are   you
```

Comment: `\n` should be "code" for the actual newline character. backslash n is just two regular ascii characters... `tr` doesn't work on strings of 2 or more characters

Answer (score 2):

So is the question how does one substitute literal backslash-n's?

If so, it can't be done with tr, since tr only works on single characters.  Here's how to do it in sed (string editor):

```
$ cat test1
hello \n\n\n how are \n\n you
$ sed -e 's/\\n/ /g' < test1
hello     how are    you
```

note the extra backslash needed to tell sed we're looking for a literal backslash here, and to not interpret '\n' as a line feed character.

Comment: So `tr` can not translate a string of 2 characters

Comment: @Xen2050 `tr` can translate strings of any length... as long as an ordering is not required.

Comment: @muru Is it really still what's commonly known as a "string" if the order doesn't matter? I'm thinking of "words" for example. But I don't think I'll ever figure out `tr`, when these two commands are equivalent it's time to get the cheque & leave `tr aaa xyz` and `tr a z`

Comment: @Xen2050 `tr` uses *sets* of characters (which is why ordering is ignored in input). When you specify `a` multiple times, `tr` only sees a single character in the first set.